# How to Generate string to update in SQL with python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to generate a string for updating values in SQL, from a python dict.
So far, I have the following:

```
def sqlquote(value):
    """Naive SQL quoting
    All values except NULL are returned as SQL strings in single quotes,
    with any embedded quotes doubled.
    """
    if value is None:
         return 'NULL'
    return '"{}"'.format(str(value).replace("'", "''"))



    part1="UPDATE products_list SET"
    
    #This parts prints with the desired format, but I don't know how to create a string with this:
    part2:
    for key, value in article_dict.items():
        print(key, '=', sqlquote(value))

    part3="WHERE product_id=article_dict['product_id']
```

How can I "concat" the part2 of the string to make a unique string that can be used later to update a sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you're producing isn't valid, since you're missing spaces between the different parts.  Also, there's no need for the `sqlquote` function, it's better to use bound parameters:

```python
values = []
sql = "UPDATE products_list SET "

# For each item in the dictionary, add to the SQL string
temp = []
for key, value in article_dict.items():
    if key != 'product_id':
        temp.append(f"{key}=?")
        # And store the value in a seperate list
        values.append(value)
# Concat the different set instructions
sql += ",".join(temp) + " "

# And add a WHERE clause to the end
sql += "WHERE product_id=?;"
values.append(article_dict['product_id'])

# TODO:
# db.execute(sql, values)
```